# How to use macports Python in a cron job?

Tags: python, cron

I have installed Python 2.7 through mac ports, and now want to have it used in a cron job. Unfortunatly, each time the cron job gets involved, the standard Python of my machine (an iBook G4 using Tiger) which is 2.3 is involved, making my job fail.

My PATH is (from the `set` command)

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

P

How can I have my cron job be invoked with my `PATH` instead of the faulty one ?

Comment: Just start the python task with the full path to python in the cron job i.e. /opt/local/bin/python - Unless has complex dependencies this should not require path changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the PATH variable is quite different in the *cron* world. Invoke the script with the full path to the *python* binary (e.g. /opt/local/bin/python2.7) and you should be good.

This can be examined by running `env` as cronjob and comparing it to the result of running `env` as yourself in Terminal:

user's cron env:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
...
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/Users/user
USER=user
PWD=/
...
```

compared to user's env:

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
...
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/Users/user
USER=user
PWD=/Users/user
...
```

---

Alternatively you may add the PATH to the crontab:

```
sudo nano /var/cron/tabs/user
```

In newer systems (probably ≥10.6):

```
sudo nano /private/var/at/tabs/user
```

Change

```
...

*       *       *       *       *       some command
```

to

```
...
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

*       *       *       *       *       some command
```

Comment: Of course, you can change the value of PATH in your crontab.

Comment: I just set the WAYBAC machine to 10.4, you will find crontabs in /etc/crontab.

Comment: @fd0 Thanx for this. My VM smorgasbord only include 10.6 and newer...

Comment: I was mistaken, `/etc/crontab` is the "system" crontab. User crontabs are found in `/var/cron/tabs` in 10.4. Source: http://opensource.apple.com/source/cron/cron-12.2/cron/pathnames.h