# Run script with crontab does not work

Tags: terminal, bash, cron

I know launchd is the way to go, but would really need to use cron in this situation.

I'm trying to run the following command through cron:

`rclone copy /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents mega:torrents -q && rm -f /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents/*.*`

This works ok on terminal, however when I go `crontab -e`and add it, it doesn't run.

I also tried adding the command to an .sh script, making executable and running it with cron, also no good.

I'm honestly at loss. I tried `touch`ing a file, and it works. For example:

`*/5 * * * * touch ~/Downloads/torrents/Test1.txt`

Creates the file just ok, however:

`*/5 * * * * rclone copy /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents mega:torrents -q && rm -f /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents/*.*`

Doesn't, neither does:

`*/5 * * * * cd /Users/x123/ && ./script.sh`  (which the script contains the command)

**Worth noting:** cron, crontab have Full Disk access.

Should I take this inquiry to `rclone` forum? Any help understanding what's going on would be super appreciated!

#### **So I learned a few things:**

1. When working with `cron`  and it seems to not work, check your `mail` inbox, it helps!
2. **Always** use *full paths* when dealing with `cron`
3. If you instruct `cron` a command, and then decide to move all this to a script, check and recheck your script. In my case, I was so wrapped up in full paths, that I forgot about the command verbs!
4. Thank you all guys for the continuous and great support. It's extremely valuable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Absolute Paths

Use an absolute (full) path to `rclone` in the command.

`cron` executes commands in a simpler environment than when the same command is run from an interactive terminal session. This means most executables can not be found without their location being fully provided.

To find the path to `rclone` on your Mac, use the command:

```
which rclone
```

The output will be the path to use. If you have installed `rclone` using the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) package manager, the path will likely be:

```
/usr/local/bin/rclone
```

See also [cron and "command not found"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298775/).

Try testing the `rclone` command without the `rm` command:

```
/usr/local/bin/rclone /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents mega:torrents -q
```

## Globs

The `*` passed to `rm` will not be expanded; there is no shell involved to do the expansion. A shell script – with an absolute path – is likely easier to get working.

## Shell Script

Consider writing the commands as a shell script and have `cron` call the script. Be sure to use absolute paths for every executable in the shell script and to pass the absolute path to the shell script in `cron`:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /Users/x123/Documents/myscript.sh
```

Comment: I also doubt whether `rm -f /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents/*.*` works as expected. It might be easer to put everything into a shell script (and use absolute paths there).

Comment: Hello everyone! So it ends up being: `/usr/local/bin/rclone /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents mega:torrents -q && /bin/rm -f /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents/*.*` ?  Because that's what I tried and still not getting any action.

Comment: Also, use `/usr/local/bin/rclone /Users/x123/Downloads/torrents mega:torrents -q > /tmp/cron.out 2>&1` to capture any output, and look at `/tmp/cron.out` afterwards to check for errors etc.

Comment: `cron` should be spamming your mailbox with error messages. Have you checked your mailbox?

Comment: @fd0 INDEED IT DID. Thank you for reminding me something so basic in Unix but that I overlooked! This type of help is always appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks @nohillside! I think fd0's recommendation actually did work. *** I was forgetting the verb on rclone *** .  After so much dealing with the script and all, I forgot how to properly use rclone, sorry! Let's see what happens when I fix it.